# How do I add a reference to a Blazor page?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, blazor

My razor page is missing a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web for the UIMouseEventArgs parameter. Where do I add the reference? I.e. How do I fix this?

Here is the razor page code:

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    int currentCount = 0;

    [Parameter] public String incSzTxt { get; set; } = "1";

    void IncrementCount(UIMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        currentCount += int.Parse(incSzTxt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My razor page is missing a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web for the UIMouseEventArgs parameter.

No, in the [latest edition](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-9/) (>= Preview9) of Blazor the `UIMouseEventArgs` are now called `MouseEventArgs`. But I don't think you should use them in a Button.Click handler at all.

```
  //void IncrementCount(UIMouseEventArgs e)
    void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount += int.Parse(incSzTxt);
    }
```

Comment: I'm just following an outdated Blazor tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnQ1Vb4fFsk

Comment: Yes, they outdate fast. The last previews all had breaking changes.